# How to drop null values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to drop null values of column 'Age' in dataframe, which consists of float values, but it doesn't work.
I tried

```
data.dropna(subset=['Age'], how='all')
data['Age'] = data['Age'].dropna()
data=data.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

It works for other columns but not for 'Age'

```
    Pclass  Fare    Age Sex
0   3   7.2500  22.0    1
1   1   71.2833 38.0    0
2   3   7.9250  26.0    0
3   1   53.1000 35.0    0
4   3   8.0500  35.0    1
5   3   8.4583  NaN 1
6   1   51.8625 54.0    1
7   3   21.0750 2.0 1
```

Comment: NULL is different from NAN

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`data.dropna(subset=['Age'])` would work, but you should either set `inplace=True` or assign it back to `data`:

```
data = data.dropna(subset=['Age'])
```

or

```
data.dropna(subset=['Age'], inplace=True)
```